# Oracle 11g: execution completed with warning

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, java-stored-procedures

I'm compile the source code below using `oracle sql developer`:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class ApiSecurityExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
     String secret = "secret";
     String message = "Message";

     Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
     SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
     sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);

     String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes()));
     System.out.println(hash);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
     System.out.println("Error");
    }
   }
}
```

then warning occurs:

```
JAVA SOURCE compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning
```

May be problem from `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Better use [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html), avoid that warnings.

```
String base64String = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray());
byte[] bytearray = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
```

Comment: Hi, I change my source code to return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(message.getBytes())), still get warning message.

Comment: did you removed Base64 from your imports ?

Comment: Yes, I did, is there alternative? Thanks.

Comment: May i know how you are compiling ? i just tried your program with DatatypeConverter and its working fine in my eclipse with java8

Comment: Hi, I used sql developer to combine source. Again, I'm creating a java file in oracle 11g. This may call java store procedure. Thanks.